# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict

Tags: python

When I try to write a `dict` to a file like so (`list` here is a list of `dict`s):

```py
for x in range(len(list)):
    outfile = open('message.txt', 'w')
    outfile.write(list[x])
    outfile.close()
```

I get an error that says `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't write a dictionary to a file, as the `file.write` method expects a string. Instead, you can use either use `print(..., file=file_object)` or `file.write(str(...))`.

Code:

```py
for index in range(len(input_list)):
    outfile = open("message.txt", "w")
    print(input_list[index], file=outfile)
    outfile.close()
```

Furthermore, you can directly iterate over the list and use the with statement to open the file:

```py
for item in input_list:
    with open("message.txt", "w") as outfile:
        print(item, file=outfile)
```

Comment: This works, but now it is only showing one line of my list, sorry I started python 3 days ago.

Comment: @charwisc what does the input_list contain

Comment: my input list contains about 8 lines of passwords, each individually retrieved with netsh wlan show profile and key=clear.  (basically showing all my profiles and unhiding all of the passwords)

Comment: @charwisc then replace `input_list[x]` with `input_list`, or if you want the passwords on different lines, `'\n'.join(input_list)`

Comment: Replacing `input list [x]`  with `input list`  works perfectly, thanks and sorry for the slightly stupid question

Comment: Is it ok to open and close the file each time you write an item?